# Component that can serve as an editor pane

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone tell me which swing component can perform same function as the editor pane of Eclipe or netbean when drag into the `JFrame`? For example, a swing component on which I can write/display codes and the same time can display some design when the button is pressed.

Comment: Are you trying to learn Swing by asking questions? I'd suggest you read the Swing tutorial (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) before going further.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with asking (specific) questions, but it's probably not the most productive use of your time at this point.

Comment: If you are starting out by creating an IDE, that seems to be a rather ambitious project for someone who doesn't understand swing very well (based on the questions asked so far).  I would recommend starting out on an easier problem to learn more about the language and UI architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) about Text and Editor panes